# How should I fix this error in strcmp function?

Tags: c, sorting, strcmp

I wrote a code to sort employee details in ascending order of employee names. I'm seeing an error in the strcmp function where it says "`strcmp makes pointer from integer without a cast`". I'm having trouble solving this, can someone please help me out? The type of sorting algorithm I used was insertion sort.

Employee details:

name, ID, age, salary respectively

```
Tom 001 25 3000
Sam 002 28 5000
Kat 003 34 3000
Alice 004 45 7000
John 005 48 9000
Rick 006 29 5000
George 007 32 3200
Annie 008 44 5500
Lucas 009 56 4700
Mandy 010 37 7500
```

```
void InsertionSort(employee array[], int size)
{
    int j;
    for(int pass = 1; pass < size; pass++)
    {
        char temp_name[20];
        strcpy(temp_name, array[pass].name);
        int temp_age;
        int temp_ID;
        double temp_salary;
        //traverse through sorted sublist
        for (j = pass - 1; strcmp(temp_name, array[j].name < 0) && j>=0; j--)
        {
            strcpy(array[j+1].name , array[j].name); //right shifting
            array[j+1].age = array[j].age;
            array[j+1].ID = array[j].ID;
            array[j+1].salary = array[j].salary;
        }
        //found the location to insert
        //copy the temp value to correct location
        strcpy(array[j+1].name , temp_name);
        array[j+1].age = temp_age;
        array[j+1].ID = temp_ID;
        array[j+1].salary = temp_salary;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great example of why I don't like complex expressions inside the `for()` loop definition.  What does `strcmp(temp_name , array[j].name <0)` mean?  [Hint: `array[j].name <0` is always going to be `false` (unless array[j].name is null), so you're passing `false / 0` to `strcmp()`.]

Comment: @Kingsley I'm trying to see if the string value in temp_name is smaller than the string value in array[j].name. All the employee details have been stored in a struct array.

Comment: The loop will try to access `array[ -1 ].name`... That is one place to fix...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first understanding of the strcmp() is required. Can check any example code or documentation on the internet. Can check this [link](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/string.h/strcmp) .

So as parameters the strcmp() function takes two strings or two pointers to character. In the code **strcmp(temp_name, array[j].name < 0)** where **array[j].name < 0** does not make any sense.

That's why the warning or error is "strcmp makes pointer from integer without a cast". The function expects a pointer but here it is something else.

I assume you wanted to write **strcmp(temp_name, array[j].name) < 0**